# How to create data property of type URL in protege

Tags: rdf, ontology, protege

I would like to create a data property of type URL in protege, but I cannot see ant URL among the available data types. Is it possible to create a data property of type URL in protege?

Comment: Doesn't xsd:anyURI work?

Comment: yep, `xsd:anyURI` is the suggested datatype to use: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Maps

Comment: Assignment 4, task 1, right? :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Protégé](https://protege.stanford.edu/) is based on the OWL 2 Web Ontology Language. According to the [OWL2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#IRIs_2):

> The OWL 2 datatype map provides the xsd:anyURI XML Schema datatype for the representation of IRIs.

To answer you question, use `xsd:anyURI` to represent URLs in Protégé.